# Can only cancel HTTP request first time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Running Angular 9 and rxjs 6. I have a weird issue that is probably caused by `takeUntil()`, but I am not sure. I need to be able to start/cancel a request (not pause, but actually cancel it). This is how I tell the browser to stop the request:

```
this.unsubscribe.next(true);
this.unsubscribe.complete();
```

You can test it out by setting your browser throttle to Slow 3G and going to this site: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kazpey

Notice the GET request when you press start. If you press cancel, it cancels the request. If you then click start again, it starts the GET request, but you cannot cancel it. Why is that?

Here is a video example that might be easier to understand: https://i.imgur.com/MT7YqEX.gifv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `complete()` on a observable, the stream is closed. It cannot be started again. So when you try to send `this.unsubscribe.next(true);` again, there is no stream open to send the request.

To keep the stream and still use it to cancel the HTTP request, remove the `this.unsubscribe.complete();`. Just call `this.unsubscribe.next(true);`.

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kstpgs).

---

On unrelated note, I assume this is only for demonstration purpose. If you really wish to bind a HTTP call to a button, it's better to bind to the `click` event in the controller via RxJS `from` function with either `switchMap` or `exhauseMap` operators (based on the requirement) to trigger the call. That way you can be sure of avoiding potentially multiple concurrent calls.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot. Not sure how that unrelated note would go, but I think this is sufficient.